# Return type of subpods.img

Tags: python, python-3.x, wolframalpha

I want my code to query wolfram and get the image it returns.
But the wolfram API's return type isn't matching my requirements.

subpods.img returns an object of class map. Discord can send only image files. How do i do that when the return type isn't compatible.
My code goes as shown below.

When I actually tried printing the type of pod.img it showed that it was actually from class map.
What should I do here?

```
async def printImgPod(ctx, img, title):
    newmessage = await ctx.send("\__\**" + title + ":\**__\n" + "`" ,file= img)
    messageHistory.add(newmessage)
@bot.command()
< all the rest of the code for the command >
res = waclient.query(query)
if len(list(res.pods)) > 0:
   for pod in res.pods:
        if pod.text:
            <code for printing text in pod>
        else:
            for sub in pod.subpods:
                if sub.img:
                    await printImgPod(ctx.message.channel, sub.img, pod.title)
```

Comment: See if `print(list(sub.img))` has any useful info.  If it's a built-in `map` object that should let you see its contents. If it's some mapping type from their library, and the above fails, then you can try `dir(sub.img)` to look at its attributes for a method like `get`.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh it shows:
[{'@src': 'https://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP104482310h658b082g763000010fd6gec6345d38d?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=40', '@alt': '', '@title': '', '@width': '334', '@height': '129'}]
[{'@src': 'https://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP104492310h658b082g763000054i8ig119039b78g?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=40', '@alt': '', '@title': '', '@width': '334', '@height': '139'}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `sub.img` is an iterator of dictionaries.  To get the URLs of the images, try

```
for sub in pod.subpods:
    for img in sub.img:
        await printImgPod(ctx.message.channel, img['@src'], pod.title)
```

Comment: img  has an unresolved reference there , so I tried sub.img['@src']. But now that gives an error : discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `img` is defined in `for img in sub.img`.  Did you include that line?

Comment: My bad. I missed that line. However , its not of File type to do await ctx.send(...... file = img) in the function printImgPod..  So I removed it and just put + img in its place ... it shows the image... But it actually writes down the url for each image making it look all messy. How do I resolve this?

Comment: You would have to download the file from that url, and then pass the path to the file on the local machine to `send`

Comment: Doesnt that mean more space usage on my device? Is there no other way? Maybe using requests?Or does requests also download the image?

Comment: You have two options: send them the url and their discord client will download the image, or download the image yourself and send it as part of your message.  You can always delete the file from the local machine after it's sent.

Comment: discord client as in the other end user?